# Latex symbols with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

This might be a very simple question but anytime I connect to a server in remote I have troubles using latex symbols in matplotlib.

The problem is this line of code

```
  xlabel(r'$v_r$ [km s$^{-1}$]')
```

If it's in the code I get this error message

typeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, dict found

I'm already using `matplotlib.use('Agg')`

Comment: What do you have in `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc`?

Comment: In the `/.matplotlib` folder I just have `fontList.cache` and `tex.cache`

Comment: This should work. Can you show a minimal working example?

Comment: sorry I don't understand the question. Maybe in the question I wasn't really clear. The problem is that my plotting routine works fine when I use my machine but if I log-in in remote it seems that I can't use latex symbols anymore. Do you want to know the content of the files in the `/.matplotlib` folder?

Comment: I meant that it might be useful to show some example of code that his this problem. But it might also be that the server's installation of matplotlib is somehow broken.